# Аналоги postgres функции на sql Server

Tags: строки, postgresql, sql-server, split

Всех приветствую, вопрос в следующем: на Postgres есть такие функции как SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, position) и STRING_AGG ( expression, separator [order_by_clause] ) вопрос в том чем или как их можно заменить на sql server, хочу заметить что данные функции не табличные, а вторая вообще агрегат для строк, находил много решений но большинство отпадало из-за не универсальности решений, хотелось бы что-то вроде пользовательских функции но с похожим синтаксисом как в postgres

Comment: Версия SQL Server 2016

Comment: А не разбежаться... чего нет того нет. [Встраивание скалярных пользовательских функций](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15) (поизвращаться с SUBSTRING и CHARINDEX), [Создание функций CLR](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver15), [Создание функций CLR](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver15).